# Wordpress /cp_errordocument.shtml (port 443)

Tags: php, wordpress

Every time I try to post a long worded article on my WordPress site, I receive the following error:

> Access is forbidden to the requested page: /cp_errordocument.shtml (port 443)

I've looked into it and it seems like a .htaccess problem to me.

Here's what I added into my .htacces and it solved the problem for a couple of hours.

```
php_value max_execution_time = 300
php_value post_max_size = 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize = 256M
```

Comment: Mightbe due to poorly configured security plugins if you installed any.

Comment: There's no security plugin installed.